# Java is installed but not recognized

Tags: apt, java

```
austin@HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$ java -version
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:
 * default-jre
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
austin@HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo apt-get install default-jre
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
austin@HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does `update-alternatives --list java` show anything?

Comment: austin@HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$ update-alternatives --list java
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_11/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
austin@HP-ENVY-m6-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Looks like some files got manually deleted - maybe try re-installing the package? `sudo apt-get install --reinstall openjdk-7-jre-headless`

Comment: Setting up openjdk-7-jre-headless:amd64 (7u65-2.5.1-4ubuntu1~0.14.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_11/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives
update-alternatives: warning: alternative /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_11/bin/java (part of link group java) doesn't exist; removing from list of alternatives

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should install the official Java. Install `openjdk-7-jre`.

The `default-jre` package doesn't really do much. I don't think it really does anything.

---

If this doesn't work, check your `PATH` variable and make sure it contains the Java install path. You can check where it is installed by running `dpkg-query -S 'openjdk-7-java*'` and look for the java binary. It is usually named `java` and is usually in a `bin` folder. Add that to the `PATH` variable.

Comment: I have already installed openjdk-7-jre. However, when I type "java" into the command-line, packages are suggested as seen in the snippet above.

Comment: After running "dpkg-query -S 'openjdk-7-java*'" the terminal displayed some .desktop files, but a java binary did not show up anywhere.